# Freemarker not loading remote template

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Spring MVC, and freemarker as my view resolver, (not that that matters)  I have multiple template loaders defined like this:

```
    <bean id="urlTemplateLoader" class="com.URLTemplateLoader">
        <property name="baseUrl" value="http://xxxx:8080/ftl/"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultTemplateLoader" class="com.WebappTemplateLoader">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="multiTemplateLoader" class="freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader">
        <constructor-arg>
          <list>
            <ref bean="urlTemplateLoader"/>   
            <ref bean="defaultTemplateLoader"/> 
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

this is designed to check a CMS server first, then use the local file.  The view resolver is defined like this:

```
    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="preTemplateLoaders" ref="multiTemplateLoader"/>  
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="localized_lookup">false</prop>
                <prop key="date_format">yyyy-MM-dd</prop>
                <prop key="template_update_delay">0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

Now the problem is that if the file is NOT on the remote server when it firsts looks for it,  it never checks again until the server is re-started. I set the template_update_delay to 0, so once it is there, any time I update it, it automatically pulls the new one, which is great, -- but how do I get it to check again if it is not there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JavaDoc of `MultiTemplateLoader` says:

> On every request, loaders are queried in the order of their appearance in the array of loaders provided to the constructor. However, if a request for some template name was already satisfied in the past by one of the loaders, that Loader is queried first (a soft affinity).

I will add a `sticky` property to it (which enables/disables "soft affinity") in 2.3.24 (expected in early March), but I can't change its default until 3.0.0 or something like that. Meanwhile, you can do that in a custom `TemplateLoader` (copy-paste the source code of `MultiTemplateLoader` and just drop the affinity part from it... should be easy).

Comment: That worked well. I simply removed every reference to lastLoaderForName.  But I have a new problem.  If BOTH loaders do not find a template,  then the next call does not even make it to the findTemplateSource() method.  I added some logging, and I see that freemarker does not even check any loader if there was no template in the first place.  I assume that somewhere something is telling freemarker "Never found it, don't bother looking again"  Where is this and can I turn it off to look every call?

Comment: After alot of testing, it breaks down this way:  If at the first call the template is not found by either loader, then adding it to any loader does not work.  If at the first call, the template IS found by at least one loader, then you can add/remove all you want and it will pick up the template (in the correct order)  NOTE: if you remove all the templates you will get a 500 server error instead of a 404.  Stacktrace says FileNotFoundException.

Comment: .clearTemplateCache(); does not help.  and neither of the template loaders are being called after the initial 404.

Comment: GOT IT --  The problem was Spring.  It was using it's own caching mechanism as part of its own ViewResolver Framework.  Just set the cache to "false" in your ViewResolver (in my case, FreeMarkerViewResolver) and that will pass caching control through to the Freemarker Configuration object, and everything will now work as expected.